# input text to a list won't work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

i got the folowing 
HTML code:

```
<h:form id="form">
      <h:dataTable id="table1" value="#{fournisseurbean.BC.selecteditems}" rendered="#{not empty fournisseurbean.BC.selecteditems}" style="width : 900px;  " var="car"
             border="3" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Désignation" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{car.itemmateriel.designation}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Unité" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{car.itemmateriel.unite}" />
    </h:column>

     <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Input" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{car.value}" />
    </h:column>


</h:dataTable>
 <p:commandButton value=" Sauvegarder "  render="form"  action="#{fournisseurbean.sauvegarderBC()}" />
</h:form>
```

And the function  `sauvegarderBC()` is a function to modify BC , the problem here is with `<h:inputText value="#{car.value}" />` , value entrend by users can't be modified and they are always = 0 .I can ensure you that everything is allright with the function `sauvegarderBC()` so the problem is from HTML part , and i think it's because i make an output and input in the same table , thank you for explaining what's wrong ..

Comment: Add the code of fournisseurbean. The problem could be the way you access the field fournisseurbean.BC.selecteditems. try fournisseurbean.bC.selecteditems with small letter b in BC due to getter.

Comment: @johny:yesss!! i'm really grateful !! i always had problems with inputting values in JSF, and now i realise that's because i always write my new objects in Capital letters!! i promise you , i'll never forget that !!